# convert a JS function to PHP (math function) - no client base

Tags: javascript, php

I need to convert some JavaScript calculusion functions to PHP.

Please help to write this two loops with PHP

```
JS:
    for (a = 0; a < 9; a++)
       z = z.replace(new RegExp('\\' + ",-+@/. ;_".charAt(a), 'g'), "NTj2M10AO".charAt(a));

PHP: 

  $St1 = ",-+@/. ;_";
  $St2 = "NTj2M10AO";

 for($a=0;$a<9;$a++){
    z= preg_replace("\\$St1[$a]" ........  , $St2[$a],$z);
}
```

and

```
JS: 

 var l = 128,
 o = (z.length) / 2,
 I = '';
 for (a = ((k - 1) * l); a < ((k) * l); a++)
    I += String.fromCharCode(z.slice(a * 2, (a + 1) * 2));

PHP :

.... ?
```

Thanks for your helps Pros

Comment: Have you tried writing the function to PHP?

Comment: I undid the donwvote, but I have to agree with Daan - you need to start to learn PHP, as you can't expect us to recode very function for you. Unless this is a one-off and so too much trouble to learn JS. If so, and you state so, you might be helped rather than downvoted.

Comment: my problem is that z.replace(new RegExp( ... Line.  that RegExp is a standard regex ? can i use same in PH or must write another style REGEX?

Comment: @mawg thanks, I am normal in PHP, my problem was understand JS code. so I must googling that JS functions and write PHP. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunately, I can't answer, except to suggest that you 1) compare the manuals, or 2) google (but I imagine that you did), or 3) run both with varied input samples & compare the results , or 4) I started off with PHP & came to JS later. If I were doing it your way, I _might_ learn PHP, but I might also look at Node.JS whcih will make it much easier for you to write server side code and almost certainly has the same regex function. Maybe that is the answer for you?

Comment: Lol - so you are primarily a PHP guy, who needs to write a little JS? If so, you might also consider AJAX - have the JS call a function on your server which you know is calling the PHP regex function, which you understand.

Comment: @mawg Yes :) .  so I'll google that 'RegExp' and 'Slice' functions to do same at PHP. thanks

Comment: Please let me know if that works. If so, you have an answer; if not, I will hack some code together later to test it, but, as usual, I am running late for a meeting. As I said, you might also consider AJAX.

Comment: @mawg thanks . I update main post.

Answer (score 1):

I solved myself

First loop :

```
  $z="..........."; // a string
  $st1=",-+@/. ;_";
  $st2="NTj2M10AO";
  for($a=0;$a<9;$a++)
        $z=str_replace($st1[$a], $st2[$a], $z);
```

second loop :

```
  $l = 128;
  $o = (strlen($z)) / 2;
  $I = '';
  for ($a = (($k - 1) * $l); $a < ($k * $l); $a++)
    $I .= chr(substr($z,($a*2),2));
```

thanks @mawg and others

Comment: I upvoterd your answer ;-)  Glad to hear that you solved it. If I helped in any way, please upvote teh corresponding comment(s), it's what encourages us to help around here ;-)   Welcome aboard, you will find lots of helpful, friendly people here